# Why is github not deleting the files that i moved

Tags: git, github

So I was working with git remote from my local machine to Github and when I made my first commit, the directory was `web/main` and then I pushed it into github. After that I changed my mind so I moved the `main` folder into a new folder called `backend` and the directory changed to `web/backend/main`. Keep in mind I **moved** it so `web/main` should not exist anymore and it didn't exist in my local machine, but in [github](https://github.com/happyprogrammer-code/gittest-django-simpleapp/tree/master/web) the folder remains there. is this intentional?

git status:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

git push:

```
$ git push
Everything up-to-date
```

EDIT:

I should probably point this out earlier but there's a single python file `manage.py` aside of the folder `main` in the `web/` in the first commit

and also IMSoP point out about `manage.py` being renamed while other files we're being copied in github. So i checked the first commit on my local machine and weirdly enough I couldn't find `main` folder which is weird because in the first commit of my github it was there.

UPDATE:

So I decided to redo this whole process from scratch

- the first thing that I did was create the same directory as
  the first commit which is `web/main`
- and then I initialized git repo in my local machine ran `git add .` and
  `git commit -m "first commit"`
- pushed it into my github repo

this is where something odd happened. I moved the `main` folder and `manage.py` file into `backend`, ran git status and this is what it says

```
 $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    web/manage.py

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        web/backend/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

so it basically didn't detect that my `web/main` folder is gone even though it didn't appear in my local machine

Thank you in advance

Comment: Nothing changes on the remote until you push the changes

Comment: I already pushed it. I redo it and it says `Everything up-to-date`

Comment: What is the remote branch where you are seeing the old folder still there?

Comment: Did you commit the move?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I only have 1 branch, master branch

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes

Comment: You can see [your commit here in Github](https://github.com/happyprogrammer-code/gittest-django-simpleapp/commit/fbef8650a9337a9e402e77ef35b9357fd4c80fb7). It shows one file being renamed (web/manage.py → web/backend/manage.py), but the other files as new copies.

Comment: Just to rule out some possibilities, can you confirm that running `ls` in the "web" directory on your computer right now doesn't show the "main" sub-directory?

Comment: @IMSoP no it's just "backend/"

Answer (score 5):

Cloning your repository (https://github.com/happyprogrammer-code/gittest-django-simpleapp), I find that there are two commits in it:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* fbef865 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) organizing the files in to backend file
* 018aed1 first commit
```

Here's what's in commit `018aed1`:

```
$ git ls-tree -r HEAD^
100644 blob b7c617c5cf9a85407c312d9e32da17de165cf81c    .gitignore
100644 blob 94ff3859fbf86be732f633254a110a860a8bbb65    requirements.txt
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    web/main/__init__.py
100644 blob 63356bd12bf3370b9b4e6411d6b24e1fe5681e99    web/main/asgi.py
100644 blob 905914bb8d0aa8951948ba5f1a5167ea4627e35b    web/main/settings.py
100644 blob e1637d6a6898f22e07fcfaee419c67565997e788    web/main/urls.py
100644 blob e1c99c8fb064bb93d7710bdf80e80231fc95343a    web/main/wsgi.py
100644 blob fbda2b3121972503edd5072a6f077c6f744abe77    web/manage.py
```

Here's what's in commit `fbef865`:

```
$ git ls-tree -r HEAD
100644 blob b7c617c5cf9a85407c312d9e32da17de165cf81c    .gitignore
100644 blob 94ff3859fbf86be732f633254a110a860a8bbb65    requirements.txt
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    web/backend/main/__init__.py
100644 blob 63356bd12bf3370b9b4e6411d6b24e1fe5681e99    web/backend/main/asgi.py
100644 blob 905914bb8d0aa8951948ba5f1a5167ea4627e35b    web/backend/main/settings.py
100644 blob e1637d6a6898f22e07fcfaee419c67565997e788    web/backend/main/urls.py
100644 blob e1c99c8fb064bb93d7710bdf80e80231fc95343a    web/backend/main/wsgi.py
100644 blob fbda2b3121972503edd5072a6f077c6f744abe77    web/backend/manage.py
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    web/main/__init__.py
100644 blob 63356bd12bf3370b9b4e6411d6b24e1fe5681e99    web/main/asgi.py
100644 blob 905914bb8d0aa8951948ba5f1a5167ea4627e35b    web/main/settings.py
100644 blob e1637d6a6898f22e07fcfaee419c67565997e788    web/main/urls.py
100644 blob e1c99c8fb064bb93d7710bdf80e80231fc95343a    web/main/wsgi.py
```

So the reason you see both sets of files on GitHub is that your most recent commit *contains* both sets of files.

> Keep in mind I **moved** [`web/main` to `web/backup/main`] so `web/main` should not exist anymore and it didn't exist in my local machine

You need to be careful here, because *Git does not use the files in your working tree* to build new commits.  Git uses, instead, the files that are in *Git's index*.  I believe I know precisely what happened, but before I suggest what I think happened, let's describe Git's index.

#### The index

Git's index is quite central to Git, yet it's largely invisible.  If you look in a (non-bare) repository, you see a bunch of ordinary files, plus—if you look closely—a `.git` directory.  The `.git` directory contains Git's databases and ancillary control files:

```
$ ls .git
branches        HEAD            info            packed-refs
config          hooks           logs            refs
description     index           objects
```

The big database (of all of Git's objects) is in `.git/objects`, and the smaller ones (e.g., branch and other names) are in `.git/packed-refs` and `.git/refs` and other files.  That file named `.git/index` is where Git's index is being stored at the moment,<sup>1</sup> but it's a binary file:

```
$ file .git/index
.git/index: Git index, version 2, 13 entries
```

What's really in that file is messy, and you're supposed to use the plumbing commands `git ls-files` and `git update-index` to manipulate it, if you ever need to go that low-level, but to describe Git's index—also known as the *staging area*, and sometimes as the *cache*—in as few words as possible, I like this phrase:  **The index holds your proposed *next* commit.**

Git will *fill in* this index from a commit when you check that commit out, with `git checkout` or `git switch`.  The actual contents are just index entries, which you can see with `git ls-files --stage`; each one has a *mode*, a *hash ID* (usually a blob hash ID), a *staging number* (usually zero), and a pathname such as `web/main/__init__.py`.  Note that these file names contain embedded (forward) slashes: there are no folders or directories at this level, just files whose names have slashes in them.<sup>2</sup>

Git will also fill in your *working tree* during this checkout.  That gives you *usable* copies of files.  The blob objects in the index are read-only, Git-ified, compressed and *de-duplicated* copies of the files' data.  Note in the `git ls-tree -r` output above that various blob hash IDs repeat: the files' data are stored only once, in each of those blobs, even though the files are "in" two commits.  In the second commit, two files both have hash ID `e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391`.  (This is in fact *the* hash ID of the empty file: *every* empty file, in *every* Git repository, has this particular hash ID.)

As you work in your working tree, you'll change the content of some files.  You might even rename files, or shuffle the tree around.  *None of this affects Git's index*, which holds *independent copies* of the files.  Eventually, though, you'll want to put the new content into a new commit.  Now you must run `git add`.

**What `git add` does is read the working tree file, compress and de-duplicate it, and update Git's index.**  If the new content matches some existing blob, the hash IDs match, and Git just re-uses the existing blob.  If the new content is truly new, Git stores that into the objects database and puts the new hash ID into the index.  Either way the updated file is now ready to go into the new commit.

When you run `git commit`, Git simply packages up *all the files that are in the index* at that time, in the form they have at that time, to make the new commit.  So whatever is in the index is now in the new commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>There's an environment variable, `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, that gives the path name of the principle index file.  That index file can refer to other files, and many details are not promised any one way or another, but the Git plumbing commands will obey `GIT_INDEX_FILE` if you set it, which allows you to use alternative index files.  The old `git stash` script, back when `git stash` was a script, used this, for instance.

<sup>2</sup>This is why Git is unable to store empty directories.  Storing a *gitlink* in the index is possible, and the presence of a gitlink makes Git make an empty directory, so that's one way to cheat: a gitlink is half of a submodule, so storing half-a-submodule in the index lets you make Git make an empty directory.  But you need the other half to make the submodule complete, to keep Git happy.  See also [How can I add a blank directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452)

---

#### Removing or renaming files

If you remove or rename a file in your *working tree*, **nothing happens in Git's index yet**.  You must tell Git to update its index.

The commands to do this include `git add` as before, but also `git rm` and `git mv`.  **The only one you actually *need* is `git add`** because `git add` can *remove* a file from Git's index.  Let's create a file *in* Git's index:

```
$ touch foo
$ git add foo
$ git ls-files --stage foo
100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0   foo
```

(there's that empty-file hash ID again).  Now we'll remove the file from the working tree, and see that it remains in Git's index, but then we'll run `git add` and see what happens:

```
$ rm foo
$ git ls-files --stage foo
100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0   foo
$ git add foo
$ git ls-files --stage foo
$
```

So `git add` will "stage a deletion": if the file is *gone* from the working tree, `git add` *removes the file from the index* too.

So, why do `git rm` and `git mv` exist?  They're there for convenience:

```
$ touch foo
$ git add foo
$ git rm foo
error: the following file has changes staged in the index:
    foo
(use --cached to keep the file, or -f to force removal)
$ git rm -f foo
rm 'foo'
```

The `git rm` command will remove the file from both the index and your working tree (and, as you can see, complain in some cases and do nothing, requiring `-f` or `--force` to do that).  Or:

```
$ touch foo
$ git add foo
$ rm foo
$ git rm foo
rm 'foo'
```

If the file is already gone from the working tree, `git rm` acts a lot like `git add`, simply removing it from the index.  Last, there's `git rm --cached`.  This is where the old name, *cache*, turns up.  This variant removes the file from Git's index / staging-area, without touching your working tree.

Similarly, `git mv` is there for convenience.  Git does not *store* renames: each commit just has a full snapshot of *every file*.  Git will, later, at `git diff` time, *guess* about renames: if the commit on the "left side" of a diff has some file X with some content, and no file Y, and the commit on the "right side" of a diff has some file Y with the same content X used to have, but has no file X, why then, probably file X got renamed to file Y.  But to get there, we have to:

1. copy the new-named file's content-hash (and mode) to the new name in the index;
2. remove the old-named file's mode-and-hash from the index; and
3. rename or otherwise update the file in the working tree, according to whatever this OS's file system rules are.

We can do all three of these at once with `git mv`.  Or, we can rename the file with the OS's file-renamer, `mv` or `rename` or whatever it may be, and then run `git add` twice, or `git rm` and `git add`, or whatever.  But running one `git mv` command is a little more convenient.

So that's what `git rm` and `git mv` are for: they're *more convenient* ways to achieve the result we want, which is to say, manipulate some file(s) in *both* Git's index *and* our working tree.  We don't *need* either one.  We can do the file-manipulation with regular OS commands, because files in our working tree *are* regular OS files.  Then we can update Git's index with `git add`, which can do everything.

#### What I think you did

By now you probably know what you did, but here's what I think you did (assuming a Unix-like system's shell commands and maybe with some minor differences):

```
mkdir web/backend
mv web/main web/backend/main
git add web/backend
```

This told Git to *copy* all the renamed files into Git's index under their new names.  But Git never *took out* the *old* names, so those index entries, with their `mode 100644` and `blob <whatever>` and stage-zero and path-name, remained in Git's index.  Then you ran:

```
git commit
```

and Git packaged up the index contents, complete with duplicate copies of each file.

#### Use `git status` to view the interesting parts of the index

Your *working tree* contains fewer files than your *index*, and if you run `git status`, Git will run two `git diff` operations:

- One will compare the `HEAD` commit to Git's index.  Since the `HEAD` commit was made *from* Git's index, these two will match exactly and this `git diff` will have nothing to say, so `git status` won't print anything from it.
- The second `git diff --name-status` operation will compare what's in Git's index to what's in your working tree.  Since the index holds files that have mysteriously<sup>3</sup> vanished from your working tree, Git will call these files `D`eleted.  With `git status --short` they'll show up here as status letter "D", and without `--short` they'll be listed as *changes not staged for commit*, with a bunch of files being "deleted".

The `git status` command is therefore very helpful:

- First, it tells you which branch you're "on", i.e., when you make a *new commit*, which branch name will be updated to hold that new commit's new hash ID.
- Then, if the current branch has an *upstream* set, it tells you about the current branch as compared against its upstream.  (If not, it skips over this part.)
- Now it runs the two diffs.  For files that *match* the `HEAD` commit in the index, they're not very interesting, and it says nothing about those, but for files that are gone, or are new, or differ, those are interesting: it tells you about those, saying that they are *staged for commit*.  For the second diff, for files that match in the index and working tree, those are dull so it says nothing, but when files *don't* match it tells you about the changed or deleted files.

There's something a little odd here.  Files that are in your working tree, but *aren't* in Git's index, don't get listed in the above sections.  Instead, this last group of files is segregated into its own section.  These files are—by definition—your *untracked* files.  Any file that exists in your working tree *right now*, but is not in Git's index *right now*, is an *untracked file*.

When working with Python code, we get byte-compiled `.pyc` or `.pyo` files (depending on optimization) whose name goes in `__pycache__` or not (depending on Python version).  These files clutter up your working tree, and if Git were to *complain about them* as being untracked files, that could be pretty noisy.<sup>4</sup>  So Git allows you to tell `git status` to *shut up* about certain untracked files.  That's half of what `.gitignore` is about.

These untracked files should also *stay* untracked.  That's the other half of what `.gitignore` is about: using an en-masse add operation, like `git add .`, will normally add *every file* to Git's index, including all the untracked ones.  But the `.pyc` files shouldn't get added.  By listing `*.pyc` in `.gitignore`, you tell `git status` to shut up about them, and `git add` not to add them.

There's one other thing you *need to know* about this though: once a file *is* in Git's index—however it got there: by `git add` or by being read out of some existing commit, that doesn't matter—once it's *in* there, the file *is not ignored*, even if it's listed in a `.gitignore`.  You would have to remove it, e.g., `git rm --cached`, to get it *out* of Git's index to get it ignored again.  Removing it from Git's index means it's now *not in* your *next* commit, once you make it, which means it won't be in Git's index when someone *checks out* that commit someday, too.  This has consequences, especially when it's already in some *other* Git commit, where checking out *that* commit means it *will* be in Git's index.  But worry about those later, once you have the rest of this index stuff down cold.

---

<sup>3</sup>No longer mysterious, now that you know.

<sup>4</sup>With `__pycache__` and the way `git status` normally *summarizes* some untracked files, you get just one line here, which isn't *that* annoying.  With the old Py2k scheme, you get one line per file, which is pretty annoying.

Comment: I appriciate you for this. I didn't do `git add web/backend` i always do `git add .` instead.

Comment: actually i redo the whole process in a new repo and new folder. Right after i moved the `main` folder to `backend` I ran git status and I found that while it only acknowledged that I deleted `manage.py` file and there's an untracked file at `web/backend`. It didn't mention that i deleted `web/main` even though it was deleted in my local machine so you were right.

Comment: so I did ran `git add .` but somehow git didn't acknowledged that I deleted `web/main` when I moved it

Comment: It's possible that you're on Windows and have picked up the buggy fsmonitor code. I don't use Windows and am not sure which Windows version has this, what triggers the bug, etc., but I've seen reports that mention something going wrong here. If you're not on Windows, this shouldn't be happening. (On Windows it shouldn't happen either of course, but you probably know what I mean...)

Comment: yeah highly highly likely. since I JUST reset my machine earlier and somehow it changed version so that made so much sense and it's  known for windows user not to upgrade windows before thorough research. I'm reinstalling it again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

git doesn't store directories.  It only implicitly creates them if you extract files that have such a path.  I suppose gethub's web view of a branch works like your normal repository.  Updating it will remove the *files* but not any resulting empty directories.  Your local directory was not removed *by git* but by **you** and then you committed the changes.  The change shows a removed file and an added file.

Comment: The consequence of not storing directories is the *opposite* of that: it means that an empty directory *never* shows up in anything that is using git as its source of data.

Comment: @IMSoP If you `checkout` something and it removes all the files in `somedir/` because there are none in this commit you checked out, you will see an empty directory in your local file system.  Deleting those files to make it match the current commit will not remove the now-empty directory.

Comment: Yes, that is true of a local working copy, but Github doesn't have a working copy, and has no "local file system" for an empty directory to be left in. It takes information directly from a particular commit in the repository, and displays it in a web interface, without ever running any equivalent of "git checkout" or "git switch". Since there will never be a commit with the empty directory in, the interface will never show such a thing.

Comment: @IMSoP OK, I was supposing that github does _something like_ a local repo to cache the results anyway, to support the file browsing.

Comment: It's possible, but I'm pretty sure it's really just a _database_ viewer, not a _file_ viewer as such. Otherwise, if 20 people looked at different branches of the same repo at the same time, Github would have to check it out 20 times.